# spring-mongodb how to get return-type of List<String>

Tags: spring, mongodb

For example, i just want to get the name from collection: users(name, password, age, email) , 
and the result type should be `List<String>`
I don't want to use `foreach` to change `List<User>` to `List<String>`

Comment: provide more information, how and where are you trying to do this?

Comment: Where you able to figure out the solution? If yes, please post thanks in advance.